# Некорректная работа массива строк

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Почему в данном случае при выводе `loadedDictionary` выводится последняя строчка файла `linesCount` раз подряд? Правильно ли объявлен массив строк? Заранее спасибо.

```
//Получаем кол-во строчек в словаре
const int linesCount = size();

//объявляем массив строк с размером linesCount
char* loadedictionary[linesCount];

//выделяем указатель для памяти под файл
FILE *dict;

//открытие файла
dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

//проверка на наличие файла/ данных в файле
if(dict == NULL)
{
    return false;
}

for(int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
{
    char buf[LENGTH+2];

    fgets(buf, LENGTH+2, dict);

    loadedDictionary[i] = buf;
}

fclose(dict);

for(int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
{

    printf("%s \n", loadedDictionary[i]);
}
```

Comment: Массив строк не может "работать некорректно". Учитесь формулировать свои мысли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что все указатели

```
loadedDictianory[i] = buf;
```

указывают на одно и то же место в памяти, т.е. на один и тот же буфер...

Более того, поскольку `buf` - локальная переменная - на **несуществующий** буфет...

**Update**

```
for(int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
{
    loadedDictianory[i] = malloc(LENGTH+2);
    fgets(loadedDictianory[i], LENGTH+2, dict);
}
```

если не хочется терять лишнюю память -

```
for(int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
{
    char buf[LENGTH+2];
    fgets(buf, LENGTH+2, dict);
    loadedDictianory[i] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
    strcpy(loadedDictianory[i],buf);
}
```

и не забудьте по окончании работы освободить выделенную память!

Comment: И каким образом можно это исправить? Уже часа два бьюсь над  этим.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Ну, если это решило вашу задачу, закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый...